# testing my REPOSITORY layer with DBUnit/Junit, should I manually build scheme or automate it? what's the advantages?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, dbunit

I am thinking on how to design my unit-tests for my java based-repositories and encountering design problems:
Lets assume I have a Consumer table with data related to my consumer:
{ ID, Name, Phone }
And my ConsumerRepository extends BaseRepository which extends JPA repo and supports **findByPhone, findByName, findAll queries and save option.**

I'm using H2 in-memo DB and DBUnit for those tests, all configured and running and was thinking about this:

1. When launching data to my in-memory DB, should I be configuring the data with the ConsumerTestData.xml (DBUnit) and manually adding the Consumer data for each test for e.g:

   ```
   <dataset>
   <CONSUMER CONSUMER_ID="1" FIRST_NAME="Elvis" LAST_NAME="Presley" PHONE="+972123456789" EMAIL="elvis@isep.com" CREATION_DATE="2017-08-29"/>
   <CONSUMER CONSUMER_ID="2" FIRST_NAME="Bob" LAST_NAME="Dylan" PHONE="+972123456780" EMAIL="bob@isep.com" CREATION_DATE="2017-08-29"/>
   <CONSUMER CONSUMER_ID="3" FIRST_NAME="Lady" LAST_NAME="Gaga" PHONE="+972123456781" EMAIL="gaga@isep.com" CREATION_DATE="2017-08-29"/>
   </dataset>
   ```

**or should I automate it?** for e.g:

```
@Test
public void findByPhone(){
    ConsumerEntity consumerEntity = ConsumerUtil.createRandomConsumer();
    ConsumerEntity savedConsumerEntity = consumerRepository.save(consumerEntity);
    assertThat(consumerRepository.findByPhone(savedConsumerEntity.getPhone()).isEqualTo(savedConsumerEntity.getPhone());
}
```

While my createRandomConsumer generates random data.

Pros:
I think automating would be much more generic and handy as if ConsumerEntity might change or any code changes next - i will not have to change my .xml file and just be able to add things to the TestEntity function.
Cons:
Creating new objects and saving to in-memo DB might be more difficult if contains any constraints in the DB scheme.

2. Should I use DBUnit at all? if automating it - why should I use DBUnit? is it better just to use JUnit (Rolling back the data after each test and just adding the data I need for the test automatically as in the example above?)
3. If chose to use DBUnit for this - and manually added - what are the advantages of such thing? why is it better than using simple JUnit with Spring?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be asking 2 questions: whether to use DBUnit and whether to use randomization.

**As for DBUnit**

- It adds extra steps and extra maintenance costs. If you already have code to save entities (via XxxRepository), then there is no reason to introduce yet additional tool.
- This is true not only for DBUnit but for any tool that duplicates existing persistence logic.
- Instead you can just create an object instance, fill all the fields and save with the repository. This makes refactoring much easier.

**As for test randomization**

- I think your test looks very good. With randomization you can cover more cases with less tests, find tricky cases that you couldn't think of yourself, isolate your tests easily (e.g. generate unique username instead of keeping track of them somewhere), etc.
- As per cons: good randomziation (and good tests in general) require a good command of OOP, so not everyone can easily use it when the project grows big. Also tests start failing from time to time because they are written in haste and not every possibility is considered. To catch such cases you should run the tests locally many times (which sometimes people forget). Good news: IntelliJ can repeat tests N times for JUnit (for TestNG there is an annotation).

In general you should think more when you write randomized tests. But if written properly they provide better coverage and lower maintenance overhead. If you're interested in different randomization techniques, [check this out](http://qala.io/blog/randomized-testing.html).

Comment: Thanks. another question related is: do I have to "save" each time data to the in-memo DB? that what will happen if I use the randomization idea, so test becomes also related with save method. but more generic, more easy to refactor and easy to control. what do you think?

Comment: Are you asking if you should use `save()` method or some other way to insert data? I think I stated this in the answer - that yes, you shouldn't duplicate code and should re-use the existing `save()`.

Answer (score 1):

1) Testing with **only** random or runtime generated fixture is not fine.
It doesn't make tests reproducible, so make them harder to debug if fails and it doesn't make tests document the code either.

Besides, fixtures with explicit data reduces side effects as the data generation may introduce.
Are you sure that the generated data respect the requirements ? 
Are you sure that your generate tool works as expected ?
Have you tested it ?
And so for...
Finding required edge cases is fine but inventing not required edge cases means your tests will change your requirements.
And you don't want that.
**If you identified all specific cases and you want to generate some data because you deem that you have too many combinations (dozen of input cases for example), of course generating fixture by relying on the requirements is nice.**
Otherwise, don't make it as it seems an overhead.

2) DBUnit, it is a choice.
Before I used it. Now, I stopped. It has some strengths but it is cumbersome and its maintenance/improvements are very light.
Recently, I tried [`DbSetup`](http://dbsetup.ninja-squad.com/) from JBNizet (a SO member).
It is rather a fine API to insert Data in a database from Java code : simple and straight usable.

For example to insert data in DB, An `Operation` can be defined as :

```
Operation consumerInserts = sequenceOf(
    insertInto("CONSUMER")
        .columns("ID", "FIRST_NAME", "LAST_NAME")
        .values(1, "Elvis", "Presley")
        .values(2, "Lady", "Gaga")
        .values(3, "Bob", "Dylan")
        .build();
)
```

3) So, nothing to add.

Comment: Thanks for your'e comment- 1.about the dynamic generated fixture- what happens if I change the ConsumerEntity fields later on? If I would like to have a last-name attribute as well, I would have to del the whole data and make it again? 2. Aren't randomness will add more features to my test? it will also include edge-cases as it will generate lots of kinds of data- or it is not what I want to test but test the DATA_ACCESS and not the data itself? 3. if so - do I need also to test CRUD operations? are like the CRUD testing operations are a must for any repository check? Ty

Comment: 1) You have to delete nothing. You have just to change your fixture dataset to add this field. 2) You implement according to a requirement, not randomness data. Inserted data have to be validated according to a specific format and not accept anything. Edge cases and acceptable cases have to be identified. Randomness will not do that for you. 3) What you want to test is not the CRUD repository. It relies on JPA/Hibernate and Spring as wrapper and you know that these are OK. What you want to test is your entities mapping and to test it, you can of course rely on in CRUD operations.

Comment: @Downvoter please respect people that take time to answer and comment your downvote.

Comment: I am not an expert in this area, but the answer reads fine to me. For the record: sometimes "random" testing is fine, for example when thinking about quickcheck ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickCheck ) . The key element there is to know your random *seeds*, so that you are able to repro a failed test easily later on.